# How to run an image of Docker above databricksConnectDocker without error "tiny"

Tags: docker, databricks-connect

When I run an image above databricksConnectDocker, I've got this:

```
tini (tini version 0.16.1 - git.0effd37)
Usage: tini [OPTIONS] PROGRAM -- [ARGS] | --version

Execute a program under the supervision of a valid init process (tini)

Command line options:

  --version: Show version and exit.
  -h: Show this help message and exit.
  -s: Register as a process subreaper (requires Linux >= 3.4).
  -v: Generate more verbose output. Repeat up to 3 times.
  -g: Send signals to the child's process group.
  -l: Show license and exit.

Environment variables:

  TINI_SUBREAPER: Register as a process subreaper (requires Linux >= 3.4)
  TINI_VERBOSITY: Set the verbosity level (default: 1)
```

Then it closes.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM datathirstltd/dbconnect:71.0

ENV PYTHONPATH .

RUN mkdir /x

WORKDIR /x

COPY . /x

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then, I create the image:
`docker build --tag X1.0 .`

and try to launch a container:
`docker run --name X_container X:1.0`

Here I have my error.

Any idea what it could be? Is it normal?

Comment: What's the image's default command?  (You don't have a `CMD` in your Dockerfile; I don't know if that base image provides one.)

Comment: RUN pip install -r requirements.txt could be a command.

Comment: `pip install` is almost always something you'd `RUN` during the image build, rather than the `CMD` that would get run when you start a container later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discussed with people that do this docker image. Here is the answer: "You will probably need to make some modifications to run it yourself directly (I've never tried). It is really designed to run as a devcontainer in VSCode - please see the instructions in the readme".

It means that:

- Yes it doesn't work.
- Yes, it's normal that it doesn't work.

I have my answer.